# PHP echoing table rows according to an array from another table

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I'm having some issues echoing out the results from table rows in accordance to an array of digits stored in a separate table.

I would like to display the books based on the order assigned in the POS TABLE pos column.

```
$arr = $pos['pos']
$sort = explode(', ', $arr);

$sql = " SELECT * FROM items ";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  $prods = $result->fetch_assoc();

  foreach ( $sort as $pos ) {
     echo $prods['qty'][$pos]; // NOT WORKING
  }
}
```

Here are the structure of the tables:

```
 -POS TABLE---------
id:   pos:
1     4,1,3,2


 -ITEMS TABLE---------
id:   qty:   name:
1     43     book1
2     23     book2
3     6      book3
4     36     book4
```

Comment: You're only fetching 1 row.

Comment: How for are you into this project? Is it too late to design your tables better?

Comment: @dan08 inherited so changing tables would be a nightmare lol.